# Тестирование со случайными данными

Tags: c#, случайные-числа, тестирование

На с# делаю машину состояний в форме черного ящика. Создается набор состояний, между ними настраиваются переходы, для переходов прописываются условия когда они срабатывают. Среди прочих свойств перехода есть такой параметр как вероятность срабатывания перехода. В момент расчета текущего состояния, перебираются все существующие переходы и если найден допустимый, то через Random проверяется сработал он или нет.

Параллельно пишу юниттесты, которые проверяют работу черного ящика. Вот задумался как проверить, что случайный переход сработает. Пока только такой вариант приходит в голову: создаем состояния 0 - 1 - 2. Начинаем с 0 и из него делаем переходы в 1 и 2 с вероятностью 0.5. Дальше в цикле запускаем машину несколько раз (много, скажем 100) и подсчитываем в каком состояния машина оказалась. В итоге счетчик по состояниям 1 и 2 не должен быть 0. Получается а-ля подсчет подбрасывание монеты орел/решка.

```
[TestMethod]
  public void WhenTransition_WithChance_ThenOk()
  {
    var builder = SimpleMachine<int>.Create(states: new[] { 0, 1, 2 }, initState: 0);
    builder.FinalStates(1, 2);
    builder.In(0).To(1, chance: 0.5f);
    builder.In(0).To(2, chance: 0.5f);
    var machine = builder.Complete();

    int cnt1 = 0; 
    int cnt2 = 0;
    int totalCheck = 100;

    machine.Change(() =>
    {
      if (machine.Current == 1) cnt1++;
      if (machine.Current == 2) cnt2++;
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < totalCheck; i++)
    {
      machine.Start();
      Thread.Sleep(100); //ждем пока сменит состояние
      if (machine.Current == 0) // если оба перехода не сработали останавливаем машину, чтобы запустить ее по новой
        machine.Stop();
      machine.IsWork.Should().Be(false);
    }

    cnt1.Should().BeGreaterThan(0);
    cnt2.Should().BeGreaterThan(0);
    (cnt1 + cnt2).Should().BeLessOrEqualTo(totalCheck);
  }
```

Может кто посоветует еще варианты как можно тест для подобного случая написать, когда есть черный ящик и на выходе имеешь только входные и выходные данные, не влезая в его работу изнутри? Смущает, что не можешь быть уверен в 100% результате теста.

Comment: Странная штуковина, но весьма интересная. Однако же может быть проще иметь (например) три псевдослучайных последовательности, причём длинных (чем длиннее - тем они случайней), и пользовать эти три последовательности? т.е. иметь на выходе логический результат этих последовательностей. Все три можно заранее быстро нагенерировать, положить в буферы, и всё брать из буферов. И по этим длинным последовательностям пробежаться можно, логику сложить и получить выходную статистику логики. Причём, вроде бы на основании этого можно даже найти минимальную длину последовательностей. Аналитическим способом.

Comment: @InterceptorTSK, не очень понял суть вашей идеи. По задумке машина состояний черный ящик. Она генерирует при помощи System.Random последовательность случайных чисел внутри себя. Вы предлагаете в самом ящике для тестирования сделать лазейку для юнит тестов, чтобы подменять работу генератора внутри черного ящика на заранее сгенерированные последовательности?

Comment: Это от вас зависит. ВЫ САМИ будете подглядывать наперёд или же нет? А вы не подглядывайте "наперёд". Да, у вас есть возможность на заранее сгенерированном - смотреть на то, что будет. Так вы не смотрите. И суть в том, что разницы нет. Вы внутри чёрного ящщика пользуете последовательность - в любом случае. И это псевдо-случайная последовательность. Но вы на такой реализации ничего не добьётесь, потому что вам же нужна статистика, и что бы её получить - вам нужно много раз прогонять чёрный ящик. Но на заранее сгенерированном - вы можете построить статистику. Это вроде бы и есть то что вам нужно.

Comment: @InterceptorTSK, не совсем то на что рассчитывал, но подумать можно. Спасибо за совет

Comment: Вы получите заранее нагенерированное, и статистику этого. Да, вы по всему этому пробежитесь и поймёте - случайное оно или нет. Но как только вы найдёте это самое "случайное" - это же и есть то что вам нужно. И уже на этом и гоняйте тесты. То что вы можете знать что будет "наперёд" в этих последовательностях [по сути для вас всё предопределено] - это же не значит что тесты будут знать "наперёд" [тесты вовсе не знают, что всё предопределено].

Comment: В некотором смысле - это как подброс монетки, только вы сразу наподбрасывайте монетку сколько вам нужно. Да и запишите эту последовательность. Но тогда вам больше не нужно подбрасывать монетку. :) У вас же всё записано. Пользуйтесь записанным. Но не читерите. Уж вы сами себя обманывать вряд ли будете. Хотя можете. У вас же полная последовательность есть? Есть. А вы не подглядывайте. :)